# How can I add new Page metadata Schema to a Page in Tridion using Interop?

Tags: 2011

I want to add Page metadata Schema to a Page which does not contain any metadata Schema attached to it. How can we achieve this?

I'm currently using an external script. I have tried searching the syntax for doing this. However, none of them have specified the Interop syntax for doing it.

```
ItemFields metadata = p.MetadataFields;
metadata["MetadataSchema"].value.Add("Page Metadata");
```

The above code throws the following error:

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

I have also tried using syntax, that allows to add/update values of the text field in the Page, however that syntax does not seem to work for updating the metadata Schema.

Comment: Can you **edit** your question and supply a few more details around where you want to automate this exactly (is it in a Template Building Block, in an event handler or in an external script etc.), and what investigation you have done yourself already?

Comment: Can you please update your question with more detail please.

Answer (score 3):

I have found the solution:

```
Page p = (Page)tdse.GetObject("tcm:12-1468760-64", EnumOpenMode.OpenModeView);
Schema schema = (Schema)tdse.GetObject("tcm:12-761677-8", EnumOpenMode.OpenModeView);
p.MetadataSchema = schema;
p.Save();
p.CheckIn();
```